# Dotnet Publish fails with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools from NuGet (CommandLineTools)

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, nuget, publishing, project.json

I was looking for about 3 days and I found no solution for my problem. We have a web app which shall be published to the IIS. For this case we have a batch file which runs a ps1-file with Powershell.exe which runs dotnet publish.

When I run this publish script and it runs "**dotnet publish**", I get the following output:

[Output on "dotnet publish"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8NQj.jpg)

```
Publishing WebAuthServer for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1/win7-x64
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The **project.json** looks like the following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "IdentityServer4": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "imports": [ "dnx451" ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "languageVersion": "csharp6"
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "config.json",
      "config.default.json",
      "config-schema.json",
      "web.config",
      "WebAuthServerSigning.pfx"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

When I delete our global nuget packages folder and restore the nuget packages with "**dotnet restore**", it puts the IISIntegration-Tools into the .tools folder.

When I tried **"1.0.0-preview1-final" of the IIS integration tools**, the publishing went without errors, but the result gave me a 502 error in the browser.

I also tried to delete the **project.lock.json**.

I also tried putting **Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils** into the dependencies section.

The **project.lock.json** restored itself with the following information for the tools section:

```
  "tools": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools/1.0.0-preview2-final": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel": "1.0.0-rc3-003121",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils": "1.0.0",
          "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0",
          "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0"
        },
        "compile": {
          "lib/netcoreapp1.0/dotnet-publish-iis.dll": {}
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netcoreapp1.0/dotnet-publish-iis.dll": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "projectFileToolGroups": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0": [
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools >= 1.0.0-preview2-final"
    ]
  }
```

The lines in our **script for building and publishing** are:

```
. dotnet build $projectPath --configuration Release --no-dependencies
. dotnet publish $projectPath --framework net461 --output $tempPath --configuration Release --no-build
```

I really do not know, why the **CommandLineUtils** seem to be missing here.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong here?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit:**

We have a working copy of the nuget dependency in our git repository. But I don't know, why it compiled different approximately a year ago. When I compile our project, I get a **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.deps.json** in our .tools folder of the nuget folder. When I compare the old one with the new one, in the working version sometimes is a **runtime section**, which is not in the new one.

Here one example. The old, working **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.deps.json** file:

```
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools/1.0.0-preview2-final": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel": "1.0.0-rc3-003121",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils": "1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0",
      "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0"
    },
    "runtime": {
      "lib/netcoreapp1.0/dotnet-publish-iis.dll": {}
    }
  },
```

And here is the non-working file without the runtime section:

```
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools/1.0.0-preview2-final": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel": "1.0.0-rc3-003121",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils": "1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0",
      "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0"
    }
  },
```

Do you maybe have any idea for this with this information?

Comment: And your build definition does include a `dotnet restore` step? is there a `scripts` section in your project.json?

Comment: Yes, before building, a `dotnet restore` is executed. Yes, we have a `script` section in our project.json. It is: `"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]`. I will insert it as an edit in the original post. Thank you.